# Как суммировать элементы изменяющегося списка в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, список

Имеется список (`spisok1`), значения которого изменяются в зависимости от некоторой функции(в данном случае `i**2 * x`). Необходимо суммировать некоторое количество `x` раз  эти значения, и записать окончательный результат в список (`spisok2`).

```py
spisok1 = list()
    for x in range(3):
        spisok2 = list(map(sum, zip(spisok2, spisok1)))
        for i in range(5):
            spisok1 = list()
            znachenie1 = i**2 * x
            spisok1.append(znachenie1)
    print(spisok2)
```

Соответственно должны получиться промежуточные списки (spisok1)

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 4, 9, 16],
 [0, 2, 8, 18, 32]]
```

И сложив значения этих списков необходимо получить окончательный список (spisok2):

```
[0, 3, 12, 27, 48]
```

Comment: Да тут весь код нужно переписывать. Я не очень понимаю, в чём тут задумка. И где-то у вас продвинутая функциональность через `map` и `zip`, а где-то обычные циклы, где они не особо нужны и можно короче всё записать. Инициализация списков тоже не пойми где. Сложно понять, чего вы хотели достичь этим кодом, у меня впечатление, что это сборная солянка какая-то, вы конструкций надёргали откуда-то, но они имеют мало отношения к самой задаче.

Comment: Берём значения списка1, суммируем некоторое количество раз,, записываем в список2. А в этом коде вообще непонятно что происходит.

Comment: Вы можете более внятно описать задачу и привести примеры входных данных и результата, который вы хотите получить? В данной формулировке мало что понятно - "некоторая функция", "суммировать некоторое количество раз эти значения"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу только предположить, что имелось в виду что-то такое:

```
spiski = [[i**2*x for i in range(5)] for x in range(3)]
print(spiski)
print(list(map(sum, zip(*spiski))))
```

Вывод:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 4, 9, 16],
 [0, 2, 8, 18, 32]]

[0, 3, 12, 27, 48]
```

Т.е. сгенерировали 3 списка по 5 элементов, а потом их сложили.

В принципе, складывать можно и "на ходу", но если хватает памяти, то лучше именно генерить списки, а потом их все между собой складывать, так быстрее и проще, чем добавлять значения в отдельный список с нулями. А если расход памяти тут существенен то можно сделать генератор и складывать данные из генератора, а не из списков, тогда данные будут генериться "на лету" и память не будет так сильно расходоваться.

Генератор получается простой заменой квадратных скобок на круглые в "списковых сокращениях":

```
spiski = ((i**2*x for i in range(5)) for x in range(3))
```

Comment: Да в принципе это именно то, что нужно, только я забыл дописать что функция зависит еще от "x", то  есть должно быть " (i ** 2) * x " . Я не большой мастер программирования, поэтому написал как мог; и код в связи с большим количеством переменных я упростил до максимума. Можете подправить название темы, чтобы суть стала понятна?

Comment: @ZenAndrew Поменял код с учётом `x`. Результат, кстати, не поменялся, потому что `0 + 1 + 2 = 3`, получается в итоге та же сумма, хотя и из других слагаемых. Насчёт темы даже не знаю, сложно сформулировать.

Comment: благодарю за помощь!  list(map(sum, zip(*spiski))) - мне очень не хватало такого метода суммировать списки внутри списка